# Action filters in Azure mobile services

Tags: azure, autofac, azure-mobile-services, action-filter

How does one go about creating action filters in Azure Mobile Service? And, yes I do wish use Autofac constructor injection of dependencies.

Glad for any help and pointers!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to register global ActionFilters? It should work very similarly to Web API. So you can do something like:

```
HttpConfiguration config = ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options));
config.Filters.Add(new MyFilter());
```

See this post for details on registering new services with Autofac: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/03/28/making-it-yours-configuring-mobile-services-net-backend.aspx. You'd use the `ConfigBuilder` constructor overload that takes a parameter named `dependencyInjectionConfig`.

Comment: Thanks. I worked around the filter requirement with a different solution but if I should need it in the future I will return to that blog post.